# Automation of simple browser actions (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, automation, browser-automation

So... I am trying to find a way to automate Firefox so I don't have to get up and click on the next episode of a show I am watching after the episode is finished.

I thought of creating a python script that will get the source of the video file, play it on a simple HTTP page and then after the episode is over, just get the source of the next episode to play and so on. However, the website I am watching the show on is streaming the video and figuring that out is too much for me to understand right now (unless one of you people can think of a good solution for that kinda situation).

So, the next idea I had is to automate Firefox so it reads the total length of the video from the page and changes the episode number in the URL after that time period has gone by. After that, I would need Firefox to automatically click two buttons on the page and the next episode would play.

How would I go about implementing something like this. I am a total newbie when It comes to this kinda "Browser automation" task so I thought I'd ask here to get a kind of foothold where I can start. Maybe it's not even possible but I kind of doubt that.

If needed: I am running Win10 and Firefox 97.0.2 (64-bit).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If everything works out I can stay in my bed and binge the whole show without getting up even once. How cool would that be :u

Answer (score 4):

Have you ever heard about `Puppeteer` or `Playwright`?

- Puppeteer https://pptr.dev
- Playwright http://playwright.dev

Both libraries can automate Firefox and even target the specific version.
Even you can use multiple browser like Chrome, Edge, or Safari (Webkit).
You can run these in Node.JS, Python, Java, etc.